# Axios onUploadProgress not being called in desktop alone (works in mobile)

Tags: javascript, axios, callback, upload, progress

I have the following code being executed to upload media.

```
const config = {
        method: method || 'post',
        url,
        headers: {
            ...headers,
            ...extraHeaders
        },
        data,
        cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken((cancel) => {
            // An executor function receives a cancel function as a parameter
            cancelFn = cancel;
        }),
    };
    if (onDownloadProgress) {
        config.onDownloadProgress = onDownloadProgress;
    }
    if (onUploadProgress) {
        config.onUploadProgress = onUploadProgress;
        // config.progress = onUploadProgress; // Tried this too!
    }
    try {
        console.log({config});
        response = await axios(config);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log({err});
        response = err.response;
    }
    console.log(response);
```

When I pass the method as `put`, a valid url (without any CORS issue), and callback for `onUploadProgress`, I find that `onUploadProgress` is never being called in Desktop Chrome browser. But it is being successfully called in mobile chrome browser. There is not device specific implementation here, the api call is same for any device.

Axios version: 0.27.2

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console or the logs?

Comment: No errors observed. The call completes just fine, and never goes into catch block.